# New to ServiceNow, how do I attach a server via web services? (DemoNow)

Tags: servicenow

This might sound completely stupid but I'm new to this.
Anyway, here's my question:

I have a virtual WordPress server (bitnami) running on VirtualBox. Currently it's in my local network with an IP of 192.168.43.11. With a Gravity Forms plugin for WordPress I made a survey website.

How do I attach my survey website to ServiceNow? I think I'm supposed to utilize Service Now Web Services, but I'm lost after that..

Comment: You might want to elaborate on what you mean by "attach my survey website to ServiceNow". You have 2 separate systems...are you trying to consume data from one, or push data to another? Also, the fact that your WordPress site is local means that your ServiceNow instance is not going to be able to connect to it, so you won't be able to consume anything in WordPress from ServiceNow, WordPress can only push to or call out to ServiceNow with your current configuration.

Comment: I'm trying to push data to ServiceNow.

Comment: So, you have raw data in WordPress, and you're trying to push that raw data somewhere in a ServiceNow instance...where? A particular table? If you're going to ask strangers on the internet to help you, you ought to provide as much detail as possible :)

Comment: Well as mentioned, I'm completely new to this and this is a sort of an assigment. All the info that I got was to make my virtualbox/ wordpress/ survey website contraption push data (answer data from the survey) to ServiceNow/ DemoNow. I guess on the ServiceNow side of things I need to define where the data comes from and a way to display it and at that I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what version your ServiceNow instance is? If it's Eureka or later, you can use the REST API: https://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Getting_Started_with_REST. All tables are accessible for CRUD operations via the Table API.

If it's prior to Eureka (Dublin, Calgary, etc.) you can use SOAP: https://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Direct_Web_Services.